# Android Virtual Audio Loopback

Tags: java, android, audio, apk

Device;
Google Pixel 6a/7a
Android 12/13
Rooted with Magisk & using LSPosed.

Currently using LSPosed module VCam, which is a virtual camera, allowing me to select a video, which then plays as the camera output.
For example, if I was to call someone on Skype, they will see the recorded video instead of what's actually on the camera.

The video/camera aspect works fine, however the audio feature does not.

The audio plays externally, which the device microphone then picks up, along with any other external volume. Pretty much, to use this at the moment, have to keep the phone in a locked box so the sound is isolated, the phones then seem to overheat.

I am trying to figure out a way to loop the audio internally.

This is easy to do on PC, but i'm having more of a struggle on android, especially doing it virtually.
It's pretty essential to do it virtually, not with any cables, as the phones need to stay on charge to avoid extra manual labour and allowing remote control of them.

Essentially i'm trying to have.

Device Internal Audio (Output) = Microphone Input
What may be a more realistic approach
Device Output = Virtual Audio X = Microphone Input

This would also then ideally mean real speaker output would be muted, as well as real microphone input.

I've tried researching this for months and keep coming up short. Am I missing a trick? Is this even possible?

Are there any other potential solutions to this issue that I am missing?

Tried different loopback apps without success. Tried turning off microphone, but of course this didn't work as then there was just no audio at all, since it's reliant on the external speaker volume to pick up the videos audio.